# Find difference between two RGB similar image

Tags: python-imaging-library

I have two RGB images and want to find the difference between two.

Different pixels should be in red color and same pixels should be in grayscale.

I tried using PIL but unable to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are after Pixel Access - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/PixelAccess.html#pixelaccess-class. This lets you read and write individual pixels in an image.

I am presuming that the two images are the same size. I have used a simple method of converting the relevant pixels to grayscale - averaging the R, G, B values.

```
from PIL import Image

px1 = im1.load()
px2 = im2.load()
imOut = Image.new('RGB', im1.size)
pxOut = imOut.load()
for x in range(0, im1.width):
    for y in range(0, im1.height):
        if px1[x, y] == px2[x, y]:
            r, g, b = px1[x, y]
            grayscale = int((r + g + b) / 3)
            pxOut[x, y] = (grayscale, grayscale, grayscale)
        else:
            pxOut[x, y] = (255, 0, 0)
imOut.show()
```